# python split list in txt

Tags: python, sorting

The text file look like this:

```
helen:9,5,7

john:5,4,3

beta:9,9,9
```

Im new to python, how do i split this?
I keep getting attribute errors:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

```
def readText(group):
    snap = []
    with open(group+'.txt','r') as text:
        for line in text:
            name = line.split(':')[0]
            score = max(line.split(':')[1].split(',').split()[0])
            snap.append([name,score])
    export = sorted(snap, key=lambda x:x[0])
    print ('Student highest score, in alphabetical order')
    for L in export:
        print (L[0]+':'+L[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = [0,0,0]
    readText(group)
```

Answer (score 1):

split is a function of str as you can see here (search for str.split)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

The second split in the line

```
score = max(line.split(':')[1].split(',').split()[0])
```

splits the string '9,5,7' into the list ['9', '5', '7']. Calling split on it again will give the error you saw.

You want score to be the max() of the list from the second split.

Also, make sure you account for what happens on a blank line. If there is a blank line and you call

```
line.split(':')[1]
```

there will be trouble.

Comment: thank you so much, but now i get this:IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That is exactly the problem I was saying you would have with reading in a blank line from your text file. You have to add control logic to deterime what to do if len(line.split(':')) <2

Answer (score 0):

```
split() #returns a list, so you can't call split().split()    
score = max(line.split(':')[1].split(',').split()[0])
```

You could just delete the front off before splitting

```
 name = line.split(':')[0]
 score = max( s[-(s.find(":")):].split(",") )
 snap.append([name,score])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the contents of the for loop to:

```
name, scores = line.split(':',2)
score = max(scores.split(','))
snap.append([name,score])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression with groups for this.

```
import re

def readText(group):
    snap = []
    with open(group+'.txt','r') as text:
        for line in text:
            matches = re.match(pattern="^(\w+):([\d\,\.]+)", string=line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            if matches is not None:
                print(matches.group(1))
                print(matches.group(2))
                max_score = max([float(x) for x in str.split(matches.group(2), sep=',')])
                print(max_score)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    readText('data')
```